# Lightning Universal Lookup Component doesn't work with healthcloud standart objects

Tags: lookup, appexchange, screen-flow, health-cloud

I'm using Lightning Universal Lookup Component in a screen flow. It works with objects like Account, Contact etc. but doesn't work with ClinicalEncounter or other health cloud standart objects.

Is there any permissions might be the reason of it?

note: The user I'm debugging is Administrator.

Comment: I assume you mean the [Synebo free app exchange component](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000ErH8PUAV)? If so, have you tried contacting the vendor? They provide contact details on the listing.

Comment: Is there any additional error information being reported by the component that you can share with us?

Comment: @BryanAnderson On the screen there is only #ERROR thing is available. In documentation they say browser console there might be meaningful error but there is nothing in console too.

Comment: can you paste a screenshot of how you are putting it in a flow and showing the attributes being set?

Comment: @BryanAnderson the only attribute which I am setting is ObjectType and only it is required. When I set it "Account" or "Contact" it works well. But if I set "ClinicalEncounter" or "AuthorNote" it gives that "#ERROR". If you think that screenshot might gives more insight, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for specifying the API name of the object you are trying to access. I noticed that this component has been around for a while and the ClinicalEncounter object is only available with API version 51.0 and later. Would you be able to check the API Version of the LWC component from the package https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_lightningcomponentbundle.htm

Comment: @pt_5858 please check my answer I just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pt_5858 just as I said in my last comment, the Health Cloud objects you are trying to access have a later API Version than what the LWC components from the managed package you are using have access to. Here is screenshot showing this:

[image]

Comment: Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Nope since it is a managed package you would have to ask the company who developed it to update it. Only other alternative would be to develop your own component